# Adding to JSON array by HTML button

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, flask

I have an AJAX call, as below. This posts data from a form to JSON. I then take the values and put them back into the div called `response` so as to not refresh the page.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {   $targetElement = $('#response');   event.preventDefault();   // Perform ajax call   //  console.log("Sending data: " + $(this).serialize());   $.ajax({
url: '/OAH',
data: $('form').serialize(),
datatype: 'json',
type: 'POST',
success: function(response) {
  // Success handler
  var TableTing = response["table"];
  $("#RearPillarNS").empty();
  $("#RearPillarNS").append("Rear Pillar Assembly Part No: " + response["RearPillarNS"]);
  $("#TableThing").empty();
  $("#TableThing").append(TableTing);
  for (key in response) {
    if (key == 'myList') {
      // Add the new elements from 'myList' to the form
      $targetElement.empty();
      select = $('<select id="mySelect" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction()"></select>');

      response[key].forEach(function(item) {
        select.append($('<option>').text(item));
      });
      $targetElement.html(select);
    } else {
      // Update existing controls to those of the response.
      $(':input[name="' + key + '"]').val(response[key]);
    }
  }
  return myFunction()
  // End handler
}
// Proceed with normal submission or new ajax call   }) });
```

This generates a new `<select id="mySelect">`

I need to now extract the value that has been selected by the newly generated select and amend my JSON array. Again, without refreshing the page.

I was thinking of doing this via a button called `CreateDrawing`
The JS function for this would be:

```
> $(function() {
          $('a#CreateDrawing').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON('/Printit',
                function(data) {

              //do nothing
            });
            return false;
          });
        });
```

This is because I will be using the data from the JSON array in a Python function, via Flask that'll be using the value from the select.

My question is, what is the best way (if someone could do a working example too that'd help me A LOT) to get the value from the select as above, and bring into Python Flask/JSON.

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '<your dynamically created element's selector>', function(event){ });` you can use the .on method in jquery

Comment: thanks for your reply, where would I put this in order for this to amend my JSON array?

Comment: `$(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function(event){ // your code here });` put the handler in the document.ready global method